# How can I delete n-times-duplicate lines in a file in Linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell, uniq

I have a few words:

```
one
two
two
three
```

And I have a file where each word is repeated n times. For example, at n=2 the given file is:

```
one
two
two
three
two
three
two
one
```

The question is how to restore the original set of words (I know the `$n` number).

Note that the word "two" should occur two times, so `sort -u file.txt` or `sort file.txt | uniq` is not an answer here!

Comment: So only `two` should appear twice in the output?

Comment: Yes, the answer is the four words (one two two three) in any order

Comment: Doesn't any of answers below help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this line gives you the **unsorted** original lines:

```
awk -v n="2" '{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)for(i=1;i<=a[x]/n;i++)print x}' file
```

the `n` could be variable, I used the hardcoded `2`. with your current input file, it outputs:

```
two
two
three
one
```

the output is not sorted, because only with your input file there is no way to know the order of your "original" file.

### test with other examples:

```
#still n=2
kent$  cat f  
one
one
one
one
three
three
two
two
two
two
two
two

kent$  awk -v n="2" '{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)for(i=1;i<=a[x]/n;i++)print x}' f
three
two
two
two
one
one

#now n=4:

kent$  cat f
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
three
three
three
three
two
two
two
two
two
two
two
two
two
two
two
two

kent$  awk -v n="4" '{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)for(i=1;i<=a[x]/n;i++)print x}' f
three
two
two
two
one
one
```

Comment: +1 for nice awk commands for this not-so-well-defined problem.

Comment: I would give -1 for encouraging users to post convoluted and unintelligible "problems", however it wouldn't do anyone any good. +1 for the effort

Comment: Originally, the problem was about parsing the PBS_NODEFILE that is used for submitting MPI-jobs to cluster with a PBS job scheduler...

Answer (score 1):

Another too:

```
n=2
inp="./in"

while read -r cnt word
do
        seq -f "$word" $(( cnt / n ))
done < <(sort "$inp" | uniq -c)
```

prints

```
one
three
two
two
```

perl variant

```
perl -nE '$s{$_}++}{print "$_"x($s{$_}/2) for keys %s' < in
```

finally, **pure** bash (4+)

```
file="./in"
div=2

declare -A w
while read -r word
do
    [[ -z "${w[$word]}" ]] && order+=($word)
    let w[$word]++
done < "$file"
for word in "${order[@]}"
do
    cnt=$(( ${w[$word]} / div ))
    for(( i=0; i < $cnt ; i++ ))
    do
        echo $word
    done
done
```

prints in the order as 1st found the word in the input, e.g.:

```
one
two
two
three
```